# How to install djvu2pdf on Mac OS X (using Macports)?

Tags: macports, djvu

It seems i can't install it even though the port `djvu2pdf` can be found using `port search djvu`:

```
$ sudo port install djvu2pdf
Warning: No port pkgconfig found in the index.
Warning: No port m4 found in the index.
Warning: No port p5.12-locale-gettext found in the index.
--->  Computing dependencies for help2man
Error: Dependency 'p5.12-locale-gettext' not found.
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade ghostscript failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

[Edit]

Strangely, after doing a

```
$ sudo port sync
```

everything went back to normal.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo port selfupdate`?

Comment: I did a `sudo port sync` and it then worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with other package managers before.

Make sure you're up to date with the package information and the package manager itself. Use `sudo port selfupdate` to do this for MacPorts.

If you only want to update the package information, use `sudo port sync`.